# Is there a more performance-friendly way to check and change the colors of a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a somewhat new programmer developing a WinForms application in C# that has the option to change the theme/colors depending on user input. Due to the complexity of the application and the amount of panels, tabs, and labels that it needs to change the colors of, it ends up being a hassle to constantly keep updating the themes everytime a new input is placed.

Currently, the selected theme is saved via 'Properties' through WinForms, which can be saved and called at anytime. The function to change the theme is here.

```
        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "Dark")
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Theme = "dark";
                Main.CheckTheme();
                CheckTheme();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }

            if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "Light")
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Theme = "light";
                Main.CheckTheme();
                CheckTheme();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }

        }
```

Because of this, I am able to call what theme the user is using at anytime, unfortunately I have to create a *CheckTheme()* function for every single form to actually change the colors of the app, and that ends up cluttering the code up quickly. For example, this is what one of the other form's theme setter looks like. (Yes, this is a separate form from the other example.)

```
        private void frmSettings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckTheme();
        }

        public void CheckTheme()
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "light")
            {
                // tabPages

                foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.Controls.OfType<TabPage>())
                { tp.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke; }

                foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl2.Controls.OfType<TabPage>())
                { tp.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke; }

                // Labels
                foreach (Label lbl in tabPage1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                { lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black; }

                foreach (Label lbl in tabPage3.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                { lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black; }

                foreach (Label lbl in tabPage5.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                { lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black; }

                foreach (Label lbl in tabPage6.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                { lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black; }

                foreach (Label lbl in tabPage7.Controls.OfType<Label>())
                { lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black; }

                // Checkboxes


                foreach (CheckBox cb in tabPage6.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
                { cb.ForeColor = Color.Black; }

                foreach (CheckBox cb in tabPage7.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
                { cb.ForeColor = Color.Black; }



                // TabPages + TabControls
                //       tabPage1.BackColor = Color.White;
                //       tabPage7.BackColor = Color.White;
                //       tabPage3.BackColor = Color.White;
                tabControl2.BackColor = Color.White;
                tabControl1.BackColor = Color.White;
                //       tabPage5.BackColor = Color.White;
                //       tabPage6.BackColor = Color.White;
                //        tabPage1.BackColor = Color.White;
                //        tabPage7.BackColor = Color.White;
                //        tabPage3.BackColor = Color.White;
                tabControl2.BackColor = Color.White;
                tabControl1.BackColor = Color.White;
                //         tabPage5.BackColor = Color.White;
                //         tabPage6.BackColor = Color.White;
                comboBox1.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                comboBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                ExtensionsBox.BackColor = Color.White;
                ExtensionsBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                //   listView1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                //   listView1.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;

                pictureBox2.Image = Tasks.Properties.Resources.QuickClean_Black;
                this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 250, 250);
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to make this more performance-friendly and user friendly? Previously I had tried to rely on a 100ms timer but that tanked the performance of the app by a lot.

Comment: cache the controls once, and then reuse that cache to reset the theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## carefully chosen identifier

```
        public void CheckTheme()
```

That looks more like `SetTheme` to me, or at least `AdjustTheme`.
But it's probably too late for a rename at this point in the project.

## dictionary

```
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "light")
                ...
                { tp.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke; } ...
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "dark") ...
```

Clearly the conditionals work fine,
at the expense of duplicating the "visit all the nodes" code.

Consider putting Color.WhiteSmoke into a `Dictionary` entry
that has `"light"` (rather than `"dark"`) in its key.
Then you could unconditionally just assign a color.

## remembering previously applied updates

Do keep track of the most recently applied theme,
so you can skip redundant assignments the next time if nothing changed.
Think of it as a cache hit.

## traversal

To better conform to the
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
principle, this code is crying out for application of
[Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Each display element should expose an interface
so a visitor can recursively visit embedded display elements.
That would let you add a cleanly separated `Styler`
which visits elements and adjusts theme colors as needed.

## common styles

Every single display element appears to have specific
theme colors that are hard-coded.

We need a better representation for that.
And then a small styling algorithm could traverse all elements,
compute new color, and apply it.

Think about the `class` attribute attached to `<div>`
and other HTML display elements.
Putting same class name on several elements
lets the CSS styling engine impose consistent theme colors
on elements which the app designer described as being similar.

You want each of your current display elements to be able to
report similar attributes, in order to simplify the logic
of your Styler when it visits each element.